# Inconsistent elements causing problems using simple html dom parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am scraping the following source using simple_html_dom.php:
http://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php

I am scraping the table elements **td.event** and **td.actual**.

Problem is, if you view the source, you can see that the td.event all have span elements, which I am stripping out like such:

```
$events = array();
foreach ($html->find('td.event') as $event) {
    foreach($event->find('span') as $e) {
        $events[] = $e->innertext;
    }
}
```

So

```
<td class="event"><span>Spanish Unemployment Change</span></td>
```

nicely gives me

```
Spanish Unemployment Change
```

However, the td.actual element is inconsistent, some contain span elements, some do not.
So the question is, due to this inconsistency, how do I retrieve the text within the span of some, and not in others ?

Eg

```
<td class="actual">46.9</td>
```

vs

```
<td class="actual"> <span class="better">54.0</span> </td>
<td class="actual"> <span class="worse">-64.4K</span> </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `plaintext` method as follows:

```
$actuals = array();

foreach ($html->find('td.actual') as $actual) {
    $actuals[] = $actual->plaintext;
}
```